# Can't run Python EXE on Windows XP

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, windows-xp

I have a problem, I cant handle for few days. I made a simple app, but its important to install it on every machine in my company. I decided to python, because we got some very old machine, with Windows XP on it, without SP3. Its cut from internet, working only LAN. 
This Python app works well on Windows 10, 8 and 7 (compiled it using Py2Exe). But I need to run also on Windows XP, almost pure sometimes, just SP2, only some antivirus or firewalls included. 
All I got in return is "system cannon launch this application". No error code in return. I compiled it on Windows 10. I uninstalled all Python things and reinstall it, to be sure I got 32-bit version. App using some modules like: sockets and mysql connector module. 
At start I had some problem with py2exe, because it wanted some strange system DLL's, but when i used "dll_excludes" for some of them, everything compliled well, and worked on Windows 10, 8 and 7, not on XP. 
I was also tried to install python on XP, and I did it, simple calc scripts works well, but it crash when I only try to "import socket" : error loading module. PATH is set as it should be I guess. 
What else can I do, to start my app on Windows XP SP2? Pls give some advice.

Comment: here the limitations under Limitations on Raw Sockets: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Build the exe on WinXP, usually the exe will run on all newer versions of windows.

Comment: Maurice: I cant build in on XP, because it doesnt start on XP as a script ("python main.py"), I got socket error, with loading module ("import socket"/"import _socket"): Import Error, DLL load failed [...] wrong configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it. Maybe someone else would like to know. 
For interpreter run. 
Solution is simple: use older version of Python. Worked with 2.7.2, version from 2011. Propably, because Windows XP is deprecated, some functions changed and are no longer compatibile. Thats why I got error, while import socked.